Current flow on the edge dodecahedron
What is the method for solving this kind of problems?
In this dodecahedron (30 edges) identical resistors are placed along all the edges. What is the current flowing through the edge AB?


Use symmetry. Try generalizing the solution for a cube of resistors.

You can solve this problem by symmetry. It may help you to draw out on a piece of paper an equivalent network of resistors. That should make it apparent that your $AB$ edge is one of a set of six edges which are "half-way" between the point where the current enters and the point where it exits.
Another way of thinking about it is to split the dodecahedron into three parts: two "halves" and a "half-way" bit. Half 1 is centered on the current injection point, and consists of those edges which are nearest it. Half 2 is centered on the point where the current exits, and consists of those edges which are nearest to it. The six "half-way" edges are those that remain, and it is this set to which $AB$ belongs.
The only way for current to pass between the two halves (and therefore also the entry and exit points) is to pass across the six "half-way" edges. Because the two halves are symmetric, there is no preferred edge between them and so the current in each of the edges must be identical. Therefore, for a current $I$ passing across the dodecahedron, the current across your edge $AB$ must be $I/6$.
